# php - Converting a string into an array with an escaped value 

Tags: php, string, escaping

I have a string :

```
{"key": "&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;dgdgg &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;"}
```

and want to convert it to an array :

```
Array (
   ["key"]=> `&lt;span style=&quot;text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;dgdgg &lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;`
)
```

any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$string = '{"key": "<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"><strong>dgdgg </strong></span>"}';
$string = json_decode($string, true);
$string['key'] = htmlentities($string['key']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode();` as that "string" looks like JSON.

You can test it here:
http://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html